# backbone - cannot loop through a collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am having trouble looping through a collection that helps populate a view with data. When I try to loop through the collection and get the following error,

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'each'

I have absolutley no idea why I am getting this error, other than the object obviosly doesn't have that method, however I only get this error when I run the drop function see code below.

Here is by backbone code,

```
GroupListView.prototype.keyup = function() {
      this.filtered = this.collection.searchName(this.$el.find("#search-query").val());
      return this.renderList(this.filtered);
};

GroupListView.prototype.renderList = function(collection) {
  var $collection, $this;
  console.log(this.$el);
  console.log(collection);
  if (!collection) {
    collection = this.collection;
    console.log(collection);
  }
  this.$el.find(".list-items").empty();
  $this = this.$el.find("#people-groups-list");
  $collection = collection;
  if ($collection.length < 1) {
    this.$el.find("#people-groups-list").hide();
    return this.$el.find("#people-groups-list").after('<div class="activity-no-show">\
    <p>To add a new group, click the + in the top right hand corner to get started.</p>\
</div>');
  } else {
     this.$el.find("#people-groups-list").show();

    collection.each(function(item) {
      //console.log(item);
      var displayView;
      displayView = new app.GroupListDisplayView({
        model: item,
        collection: $collection
      });
      return $this.append(displayView.render());
    });
    return this;
  }
};

GroupListDisplayView.prototype.render = function() {
      var $body;
      //console.log(this.model.toJSON());
      this.$el.html(this.template({
        m: this.model.toJSON()
      }));
      $body = this.$el.find(".card-body");
      $.each(this.model.get("people"), function(i, person) {
        var personTile;
        this.person = new app.Person({
          id: person.id,
          avatar: person.avatar,
          first_name: person.first_name,
          last_name: person.last_name
        });
        console.log(this.person);
        personTile = new app.PersonTileView({
          model: this.person
        });
        return $body.html(personTile.render());
      });
      return this.$el.attr("id", "group-card-" + this.model.id);
    };

GroupListDisplayView.prototype.drop = function(e) {
      var $collection, $model, person_id, request;
      e.preventDefault();
      $collection = this.collection;
      person_id = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('Text');
      request = new app.PersonGroupAdd;
      $model = this.model;
      return request.save({
        async: true,
        wait: true,
        person_id: person_id,
        group_id: this.model.get("id")
      }, {
        success: function(d) {
          return $model.fetch({
            async: true,
            wait: true
          });
        }
      });
    };

GroupListView.prototype.initialize = function() {
      this.collection.on("change", this.renderList, this);
      this.collection.on("reset", this.render, this);
      return this.renderList();
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead, place this function with in your collection

```
parse: function (data) {

            data.forEach(function (item) {

                displayView = new app.GroupListDisplayView({
                  model: item,
                  collection: $collection
                });
            });
        }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the `drop` function has to do with it, but I see `renderList` being passed the results of `searchName` during `keyup`. What's likely happening is that `searchName` is returning a regular array, instead of a wrapped object that would have the `each` method (i.e. a Backbone.Collection, jQuery collection or Underscore wrapped object).

Instead of calling `collection.each`, use jQuery or Underscore:

```
$.each(collection, function(i, item) { ... });
```

or

```
_.each(collection, function(item, i, list) { ... });
```

Comment: Doing this I get the following,

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'on' of undefined

Which references this, 

this.collection.on("change", this.renderList, this);
this.collection.on("reset", this.render, this);

Comment: I don't see those `on` calls in the code you posted, but maybe you need to set the context of the `each` callback with `_.bind` or `$.proxy`?

Comment: Does `GroupListView` get instantiated within `GroupListDisplayView.initialize`? If not then where? Sounds like the call to `new GroupListView` isn't being passed the correct `collection` argument.

Comment: I think the problem stems from GroupListView.prototpye not being passed the correct collection, if I console.log(collection) within the renderList function I get undefined returned...why would this be if the call that runs that function is passing through this.filtered as the collection argument?

Comment: Post the source of the `searchName` function. It's not a standard part of `Backbone.Collection` so it's impossible for me to know what's going on inside it.